# Python Youtube API: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u279c' in position 7741: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to use the Youtube API in Python, here is my code:

```
import googleapiclient.errors
import googleapiclient.discovery
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api = '*******************************************'


def main():
    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, developerKey=api)

    request = youtube.search().list(
        part="snippet",
        maxResults=25,
        q="star wars"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This should send a request for search results from the query "star wars", but instead I am getting the error in the title. Using the default search query of "surfing" seems to work, but anything else doesn't. If it matters, I am using Windows and Atom Text Editor.

Comment: Try `print(json.dumps(response, ensure_ascii = True))` instead. (Of course, have `import json` too.)

Comment: This worked, thank you!

Comment: The reason of your issue is that your Windows terminal is unable to display the Unicode codepoint [`U+279C`](https://codepoints.net/U+279C). If you'll look up carefully, the terminal output should have that character escaped as `\u279c` (and similarly all other non-ASCII characters for that matter).

Comment: I understand now, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to add an answer to this question for anyone who has a similar problem. The simplest solution is (as [stvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8327971/stvar) answered):

> Try `print(json.dumps(response, ensure_ascii = True))` instead. (Of course, have `import json` too.)

The Windows terminal is unable to display certain characters, ensuring ASCII fixed this issue.